# How to pass multiple arguments to osascript?

Tags: macos, shell, arguments, applescript

I've got the following shell script which uses `osascript` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
on run argv
  tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "echo " & quoted form of (item 1 of argv) & " " & quoted form of (item 2 of argv)
  end tell
end run
```

However when I run, the code is only limited to print 2 first arguments.

E.g. when running `./test.sh foo bar buzz ...`, I expect all the arguments to be displayed.

How I can convert the above code to support multiple unlimited number of arguments? And it won't break when I specify none?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a repeat loop to map the argument list to their `quoted form` and then join the list to a space separated string with `text item delimiters`

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
on run argv
    set argList to {}
    repeat with arg in argv
        set end of argList to quoted form of arg
    end repeat
    set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, space}
    set argList to argList as text
    set text item delimiters to TID

    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "echo " & argList
    end tell
end run
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, **AppleScript's** `text item delimiters` is `{}` and unless is was set to other then the *default* elsewhere in the *script* before this and not reset as one should directly after the manipulation, and or you just are not using **AppleScripts's** `text item delimiters`, then  here is a way to do it without having to explicitly use code like e.g. `set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, space}` and `set text item delimiters to TID`:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run argv

    set argList to {}
    repeat with arg in argv
        set end of argList to quoted form of arg & space
    end repeat

    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "echo " & argList as string
    end tell

end run
```

Comment: Practically you are using `text item delimiters`, too. The expression `argList as string` joins the list to a string considering the current text item delimiters.  If they are not set to the default list of empty string you will get unexpected behavior.

Comment: @vadian, I have reworded my answer. Also I have lots of scripts where I never explicitly use **AppleScript's** `text item delimiters` but do use a list I built-out with a space as I've shown and then flatten the list. This is IMO a much easier way to code for this scenario and why I offered it.